# Does Hyper-V have to be the only role on 2012 R2 Standard?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v

At the moment, I have a 2012 R2 Standard server that hosts two virtual machines but also has AD DS role, as well as DNS/DHCP/File server roles. The domain is small (~30 users) and there's plenty of breathing room.

Would I benefit from creating additional VM (or VMs) and moving all the roles but Hyper-V to them? Is it worth the effort? What benefits do I get? What problems will I have if I don't do it?

Comment: `Would I benefit from creating additional VM (or VMs) and moving all the roles but Hyper-V to them?` - Yes.

Comment: @joeqwerty understood and added more questions

Answer (score 0):

> Would I benefit from creating additional VM (or VMs) and moving all
>   the roles but Hyper-V to them?

Yes, really easier for maintenance, some examples;

- It allow you to quickly snapshot your server before a change (and go back in case of a fail)
- It allow you to move the VHDX file easily in case of a server crass (if you have a backup off course) You are no longer bond to a physical server. A example, the server crash you can restart the server on any computer with hyper-v enabled.
- The day you got a second hyper-v's host with a shared storage, you could migrate from a host to another to do maintenance in the physical's host.

Yes for the licensing as you will be more covered, as Microsoft allow a free usage of a hyperv host if no other role is on it.  One standard give you 2 vm usage + the hyperv host. (1:2, but your core must be licensed correctly).

[image]

from [there](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/3/9/F39124F7-0177-463C-8A08-582463F96C9D/Windows_Server_2012_R2_Licensing_Datasheet.pdf)

Comment: I don't need to worry about the licenses for now. One of the VMs runs Linux and another is a temporary one, for some testing purposes. How exactly will maintenance get easier? I'm missing a point here.

Comment: @dfo for the maintenance; After a backup, you can restore where you want in case of a crash, not tied to a machine x. Before installing something you can snapshot the server